# Can I use arrayformula in Google Sheets to count things over a variable range?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

Is it possible to create a single arrayformula that does the same thing as the following column of formula:

```
A1: =COUNTA(B1:B1)
A2: =COUNTA(B1:B2)
A3: =COUNTA(B1:B3)
...
A9: =COUNTA(B1:B9)
```

My best try was `=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTA(INDIRECT("B$1:"&B1:9))` but I get a circular dependency error - I presume because Arrayformula doesn't know which of the two possible ranges to expand over. I'd sort of need to tell it which array to expend and which not. Maybe there's a notation like "::" for that? Would be cool anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Formula

`=ArrayFormula(MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(B1:B9)<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(B1:B9)))*ISTEXT(B1:B9)*1),ISTEXT(B1:B9)*1))`

What you are looking to do is called "running total".

The above formula use arrays,  `TRANSPOSE`, `MMULT` (matrix multiplication), `ISTEXT` and unity multiplication (to parse TRUE as 1 and FALSE as 0) instead creating a  `COUNTA` formula chain.

The first argument of `MMULT` creates a variant of a lower triangular matrix (all the values above the main diagonal are zero). Instead of all lower values be 1, they are 1 if the corresponding values are a text values, and 0 if not.

NOTE: Not all the spreadsheet functions are able to handle an array as argument. `INDIRECT` is one of those functions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and expand it :

```
=COUNTA(INDIRECT("B1:B"&ROW(B1)))
```

**Note** :

```
=ArrayFormula(COUNTA(INDIRECT("B1:B"&ROW(B1:B6)))) 
is  
Arrayformula ( COUNTA ( =INDIRECT(B1:B{1;2;3;4;5;6}   )   )
```

> `=INDIRECT()`
>   Returns a `cell reference` specified by a string.

[Source](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en)

Comment: This is wrong: "in this case because `"B1:B"&ROW(B1)` is already a range", that is a text value, not a range.

Comment: Ok I edited it !

Comment: IMHO the note isn't clear as `Arrayformula ( COUNTA ( =INDIRECT(B1:B{1;2;3;4;5;6}   )   )` doesn't use the Google Sheets formula syntax. I think that you should explain it.